# Why is scaled action required while training a policy gradient algorithm for reinforcement learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Below is the code I used to train a policy gradient on the CartPole-V1 environment.

```
def discount_rewards(rewards, gamma = 0.99, standardize = False, normalize = False):
    len_episodes = len(rewards)
    discount_factors = np.power(0.99, np.arange(1, len_episodes + 1, 1))
    
    discount_rewards = discount_factors * rewards
    
    if standardize:
        discount_rewards = (discount_rewards - np.mean(discount_rewards)) / (np.std(discount_rewards) + 1e-10)
        
    if normalize:
        discount_rewards = discount_rewards / np.max(discount_rewards)
        
    return discount_rewards
```

Here is the custom loss function.

```
def log_policy_loss(discount_rewards, action_prob_):

    return -K.sum(discount_rewards * K.log(action_prob_))
```

Here is the model architecture. As you can see I pass the custom loss function to the model.

```
def model():
    policy = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(24, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (4, )),
        layers.Dense(120, activation = 'relu'),
        layers.Dense(2, activation = 'softmax')
    ])
    
    return policy
    
policy_model = model()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.1)
policy_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = log_policy_loss)
```

Finally the training loop.

```
MAX_DUR = 2000
MAX_EPISODES = 3000
gamma = 0.99
score = []
for episode in range(MAX_EPISODES):
    
    current_state = env.reset()
    done = False
    transitions = list()
    
    for t in range(MAX_DUR):
        env.render()
        
        action_probs = policy_model(np.expand_dims(current_state, axis = 0)).numpy()[0]
        action_to_be_taken = np.random.choice(2, p = action_probs)
        previous_state = current_state
        current_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action_to_be_taken)
        transitions.append((previous_state, action_to_be_taken, t+1))
        if done:
            break
            
    episode_len = len(transitions)
    score.append(episode_len)
    reward_batch = np.array([r for (s, a, r) in transitions])
    discount_reward = discount_rewards(reward_batch[::-1], normalize = True)
    state_batch = np.array([s for (s, a, r) in transitions])
    action_batch = np.array([a for (s, a, r) in transitions])
    
    pred_batch_probs = policy_model(state_batch)
    pred_batch_action = [np.random.choice(2, p = p.numpy()) for p in pred_batch_probs]
    
    actions_one_hot = np.zeros((episode_len, 2))
    actions_one_hot[np.arange(episode_len), action_batch] = 1

    scaled_action = discount_reward[:, np.newaxis] * actions_one_hot
    
    policy_model.train_on_batch(state_batch, scaled_action)
    
    if episode % 100 == 0:
        print(f'Episode : {episode} , Average reward : {episode_len}')
```

My question is why am I passing **scaled_action** to `train_on_batch` as the custom loss function doesn't use **scaled_action** to compute the loss. The custom loss function only uses the **reward** and the **predicted probability** to compute the loss.

I tried training without passing the **scaled_action**, but then the model didn't learn. Asked Chatgpt but couldn't answer it.

What am I missing?